# JSON output or load() jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, json, load

I was thinking about it and didn't really find it anywhere.

What is better/faster?

returning a JSON from ajax call or just load a php file?

The result is same. But what about the overall performance and potential troubles?

Comment: wat? AJAX is about sending a request to the server (which can return JSON, but is not required). Can you please explain a bit more about the 2 options you see?

Comment: Yes, I think I wasn't really clear about what I'm asking. Let's say that I have an onclick function that is supposed to append some stuff to an element from php file. Now I have 2 choices, one is that I set up a "fake" ajax call to get the result of php file through json, or just to load the php file into the element accordingly

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use an PHP output after an AJAX call. If you, for example, update a tree structure, just send PHP the data (it saves it for a complete reload) and do the DOM operation locally.

Comment: But I need the php output as this is supposed to be a chat related content

Comment: Do it like stackoverflow itself : AJAX with returned JSON.
You could start some operations within the `success`part of [jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @Pero - I'm actually doing it with a success for a long time. But I asked a different question :)

Comment: @StevenDropper ok, could you provide more information about what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Pero - Simply - What is faster? an ajax call with a json result of php file, or a load(phpfile) jquery function? both will have the same output.

Comment: @StevenDropper ... i reread your entire Question, now i know what you would like to know :D
I don't think there are big differences in time, just some ms. Maybe try it with a small example. I'm a fan of JSON, so i would use JSON over a `load`